# Given a cartesian equation get points in the plane

Tags: parametric, implicit-function

I hope this make sense. I'm trying to understand (I'm very newbie with curves) how could I get points from a cartesian equation.

For example, given $(x^2+y^2)^2-2a^2\cdot(x^2-y^2)-a^4+c^4=0$ that is the cartesian equation for the Cassian Ovals:

[image: ...]

I would like to know how to know the points (like in this image). (I'm doing a program that represent points on a texture)

I know that resolving the parametric equation of this (I don't know if this can be done) I can give as much points as iterations done.

But I'm not sure if I can achieve that only with the cartesian equation.

Maybe, if do `x=<something>` and I try to resolve for this?

Comment: there are infinitely many points. What do you mean how to "get" the points?

Comment: Well, yes I only want to know the x and y (point) for a serie of number (maybe from 0 to 100). For a circle is easy: $x=a*sin(t) and $y=a*cos(t) where a is the squared radius and and t the current iteration. I would like to do something similar but with cartesian equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the present curve, after the change of variables

$$
x = r\cos\theta\\
y = r\sin\theta
$$

we arrive to

$$
f(r,\theta) = c^4+r^4-a^4 - 2 a^2 r^2 \cos (2 \theta )= 0
$$

and solving for $r$

$$
r(\theta) = \pm\sqrt{a^2 \cos (2 \theta )\pm\frac{\sqrt{a^4 \cos (4 \theta )+3 a^4-2 c^4}}{\sqrt{2}}}
$$

NOTE

Also another way to do that is to find the explicit dependence $y = g(x)$

Calling $x_2 = x^2, y_2 = y^2$ we have

$$
(x_2 + y_2)^2 - 2 a^2 (x_2 - y_2) - a^4 + c^4 = 0
$$

now solving for $y_2$

$$
y_2 = \sqrt{2 a^4+4 a^2 x_2-c^4}-x_2-a^2
$$

then finally

$$
y = \pm\sqrt{\sqrt{2 a^4+4 a^2 x^2-c^4}-x^2-a^2}
$$

Comment: Well, this is the polar equation... But with this I would need to make a circular sweep to get the radius on each degree... I would like to know if there is any method to get the representation (a integer point) on the plane without getting the parametric equation. Thanks.

Comment: @z3nth10n Please. See attached note.

Comment: Yep, this is what I did: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E2-2a%5E2(x%5E2-y%5E2)-a%5E4%2Bc%5E4%3D0 as you can see: https://i.gyazo.com/0553fee37d290d178d2a2ab0f6957261.png thanks!